# Accessing a file from my dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a text file within my dll. Whenever I try to access it from my .exe program, it fails because it tries to find the file from within my .exe program. Please is there anyway I can go about this.

Comment: can you explain? can you share code?

Comment: You need to load the Assembly for the DLL and not the Executing assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the assembly and using resourcemanager you can retrieve the text file as below

```
// Gets a reference to the same assembly that 
// contains the type that is creating the ResourceManager.
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;

// Gets a reference to a different assembly.
System.Reflection.Assembly myOtherAssembly;
myOtherAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("ResourceAssembly");

// Creates the ResourceManager.
System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new 
   System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", 
   myAssembly);

// Retrieves String and Image resources.
UnmanagedMemoryStream x = myManager.GetStream("StringResource");
```

For more information, please visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28VS.71%29.aspx